# Choose subtitle language MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, movie, subtitle

I'm developing an iOS app which is able to display video ( streaming ).

My app has 4 languages, which can be overrided by the user ( the app language does not depends off device language ).

In my videos, many subtitles languages are available ( include my 4 app language ).

My issue is : **can I force the appropriate subtitle for the video ?**

Right now, the subtitle are always german, and the user has to change it by itself.

**NB** : I use MPMoviePlayerViewController because I have to support iOS 7.

Thanks